# Expand formulas when copying

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The script copy-pastes all formulars one column to the right but The formula has to expand to the right too.

Example:  A1+A3  ->  B1+B3

right now the formula just gets duplicated when running the sript

```
function copyFormulas() {
  var activeSheet,numberOfSourceColumnsToGet,sourceColumnStart,sourceFormulas,sourceRange,
      sourceRowStart,targetColumn,targetRange,targetRowStart;

  //USER INPUT

  sourceRowStart = 1; //Row to start getting formulas from
  sourceColumnStart = 4; //Column to start getting formulas from
  numberOfSourceColumnsToGet = 1; //Number of columns to get formulas from

  targetRowStart = 1; //Row to start copying formulas to
  targetColumn = 5; //Column to start copying formulas to

  //END OF USER INPUT

  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sourceRange = activeSheet.getRange(sourceRowStart, sourceColumnStart, activeSheet.getLastRow(), numberOfSourceColumnsToGet);

  sourceFormulas = sourceRange.getFormulas();//Get only formulas from the source range

  targetRange = activeSheet.getRange(targetRowStart,targetColumn,sourceFormulas.length,sourceFormulas[0].length);

  targetRange.setFormulas(sourceFormulas);//Copy the formulas to the target range
}
```

Comment: You can try [Range.copyTo(dest)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) method, which is more direct than `getFormulas+setFormulas`

Answer (score 0):

As @АлександрЕрмолин says, you are using the wrong command. Try this:

```
function so5657743702() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetname = "56577437";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var sourcerange = sheet.getRange("A4");
  var targetrange = sheet.getRange("B4");
  sourcerange.copyTo(targetrange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);
}
```